# Nuxt.js: use alternative layout for mobile/desktop on every page

Tags: vue.js, mobile, layout, nuxt.js

Nuxt adds a layout property that you can set for each page. If it's missing, Nuxt uses the default layout. You can have a separate layout for mobile and specify that a particular page uses the mobile layout by including this in the script portion of the vue component:

```
export default {
  layout: 'blog',
  // OR
  layout(context) {
    return 'blog'
  }
}
```

Source: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-layout/

Eventually our application may have hundreds of pages/routes and rather than adding a layout method to every single one which checks to see if it's a mobile user agent. Is there a way to add it to all page components (without also adding it to all Vue components) in the project?

Comment: You can modify your layout (blog.vue) instead to be able alter for mobile/desktop instead add this logic to hundreds of .vue files.

Comment: I've considered that, but I would like a completely different layout for mobile.

Comment: Its okay, you can make two different components: blog-mobile.vue and blog-desktop.vue, and then v-if it on the blog.vue layout

Answer (score 2):

You can try make this approach:

`layouts/blog.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <blog-mobile v-if="isMobile" />
      <blog-desktop />
  </div>
</template>
```

And because `<Nuxt />` is accessible only in layouts, you can try pass it as slot for example:

```
<blog-mobile v-if="isMobile">
  <Nuxt />
</blog-mobile>
```

`BlogMobile.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>this is blog mobile layout</p>
    <slot></slot> <!-- Your <Nuxt /> come here -->
  </div>
</template>
```